# Ajax call return HTTP 401 after upgrade to 2.2.0

Tags: jquery, cordova

I just update my app's phonegap from 0.9.3 to 2.2.0 and I tested the apps on a few device.

- For Android 2.3 - the apps is working fine(able to do a ajax call with username and   password).
- For Android 4.0 - Keep on getting return HTTP 401.
- For Android 4.1.2 - Keep on getting return HTTP 401.

I am using jquery.mobile-1.0a2 too in my apps.

Anyone have any idea how to solve the ajax call keep on returning HTTP 401 problem for Adroid version 4.0 and 4.1.2 ?

Below is my code for the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
username: uname,
password: pword,
cache: false,
url: baseURL+'weeks',
timeout: (14*1000),
dataType: "xml",
error: loginErrorHandler,
success: weeksParse,
});
```

Comment: Try to whitelist your domain, read more here:http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html and more here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html

Comment: I did that but the apps is still not able to do the service call. I am allowing <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <access origin="https://*"/> <access origin="https://.*"/>. I also set support.cors and mobile.allowCrossDomainPages to true but the apps is still not able to do the ajax call

Comment: We do a similar call in our app but we do it slightly diffrent, `var req = $.ajax({ url: url, dataType: "xml", timeout: 30000 });` then we do `req.success(function(data){ ... });`